# rangeOfString fails with CLPlacemark value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to detect if placemark values contain certain values.  To do that I'm using the rangeOfString method on NSString.  However, rangeOfString works on strings like I would expect but not how I would expect on placemark values.  I cannot figure out why that might be.

Here's an example:

```
NSString *streetNumber = @"243-244";  //same value as the placemark.subThoroughfare
NSRange range1 = [streetNumber rangeOfString:@"-"];  //correctly identifies the range.location as 4
//placemark.subthoroughfare is 243-244
NSRange range2 = [placemark.subThoroughfare rangeOfString:@"-"];  //range.location = max int
```

If you set the simulator location to San Francisco the current location placemark subthoroughfare contains a "-"

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how you would deal with it?

Comment: It might be a unicode dash instead of a regular dash.

Comment: That's a good thought.  I didn't consider that since placemark.value is supposed to return an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Anna's suggestion was correct.  Doing some checking I was able to determine that the placemark string was not entirely ascii.  To fix the issue I converted the string to ascii first:

```
NSData *asciiData = [placemark.subThoroughfare dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *streetNumber = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

The new `streetNumber` string now works as you would expect with the `rangeOfString` method.